# delete function for databaseobject

Tags: vba, ms-access

the following code is a convenience tool to delete a table if it already exists in a database:

```
Function DeleteTableIfExists(tablename As String)
If Not IsNull(DLookup("Name", "MSysObjects", "Name='" & tablename & "'")) Then
CurrentDb.TableDefs.Delete (tablename)
End If
End Function
```

i wanted to extend this function for all database objects ( e.g. forms and queries ). is there a way to do it without making a case distinction ( by some build in vba function that i am not aware of)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, different object types need different delete methods.

So you need a `Select Case` distinction.